# Model Structure - relationships for enterprise crm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, model

I'm working on a crm solution and so this will contain a 2 part question but I am hoping someone out there will be able to keep me heading in the right direction.

First, I have a few different models (Company, User, Clients, Leadsource) and I need to add addresses and contacts to "Clients". Here is the current structure (the / is only for displaying next line purposes here on stack):

```
Company Model -> 
Has_many :users /
Has_many :clients, through: :users

User Model ->
Belongs_to :company /
Has_many :clients

Client Model ->
Belongs_to :user /
Belongs_to :company /
belongs_to :leadsource

Leadsource Model ->
has_many :clients
```

Now I need to add addresses and contacts to clients. Reasoning is that a client can have multiple locations and many contacts. Here is what I am thinking...

```
Address/contacts Model ->
belongs_to :client

New client model ->
belongs_to :company /
has_one :leadsource /
has_many :addresses /
has_many :contacts
```

Is this correct?

What's the best option in creating a form for this setup? Nested form? Multiple steps? Of course I'd prefer to have it as a 1 step nested form but need to have a client_id before I can save it into my address and contact model... right?

Comment: Why do you want a Company model to has many clients through users, instead of letting a Company model directly have many clients?  According to [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), if you do need to use has-many-through relationship here, you should design the models like this: Company Model -> has_many :clients through: :users; User Model -> belongs_to :company, belongs_to :clients; Client Model -> has_many :companies through: :users

Comment: That's a great question. I thought that is how I would need to do it if I wanted to pull a list of a specific company's clients. Users are the ones that create the clients, company doesn't actually log in or manage anything other than having users that belong to it.